# Sufficient condition for this statement about the derivative of the graph of a parametrized curve.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, parametric

My question concerns a map 
\begin{align}
\gamma:A\subset\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2,\qquad t\mapsto \gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))
\end{align}
such that $x:A\to\mathbb R$ and $y:A\to\mathbb R$ are differentiable at an interior point $t_0\in A$ and such that $(\text{d} x/\text{d} t)(t_0)\neq 0$. Let us call this situation (1).

I was wondering what are the *minimal* additional conditions that $x,y$ must satisfy in order to be able to conclude that the real-valued function $f$ defined by $x(t) \mapsto y(t)$ is well-defined in a neighborhood of $x(t_0)$ and differentiable at $x(t_0)$ with 
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d} f}{\text{d} x}(x(t_0)) = \frac{(\text{d} y/\text{d} t)(t_0)}{(\text{d} x/\text{d} t)(t_0)}\quad .
\end{align}

Let us call this result (2). I managed to prove that the following condition is sufficient, but I'm wondering if there is a less restrictive sufficient condition.

**Sufficient condition 1.** *If, in situation (1), $x$ is continuous and injective in a neighborhood  of $t_0$, then result (2) holds.*

In particular, this implies another sufficient condition.

**Sufficient condition 2.** *If, in situation (1), $x$ is $C^1$ in a neighborhood  of $t_0$, then result (2) holds.*

If there is a less restrictive (but still simple) sufficient condition, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: @PaulSinclair The implicit function theorem requires that the function be $C^1$, so it cannot provide a condition less restrictive than my sufficient condition 2, if I'm not mistaken.